# why facebook photo album returns an empty array?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm using the Facebook SDK with Laravel 4. Do I need to return the images of a user you log in via Facebook.

When I use the user, which is the APP administrator on Facebook, images and albums are returned normally.

However, when I try to do this with any user other than administrator, it returns an empty array.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
$session = new FacebookSession(Session::get('facebook.token'));

$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/me/albums',
    ['fields' => 'name,photos.limit(20){source},id']
);

$response = $request->execute()->getGraphObject();

$imagesOfAllAlbums = [];

foreach ($response->asArray() as $albuns) {

   foreach ($albuns as $k => $album) {

        if (empty($album->photos)) continue;

        foreach ($album->photos as $images) {

            foreach ($images as $image) {

                if (empty($image->source)) continue;

                $imagesOfAllAlbums[$album->name][] = $image->source;
            }
        }
   }
}

count($imagesOfAllAlbums); // 0
```

If first example, that return so:

```
[
   'Nome do Album' => [
         'imagem_1.jpg',
         'imagem_2.jpg',
    ]
]
```

In another part of code, i added the permission for `user_photos`:

```
$urlFacebook = $helper->getLoginUrl([
                FacebookPermissions::USER_PHOTOS,
            ], 'v2.4');
```

Comment: I can read "code" but not Spanish. Italian, yes, but not Spanish. scusi. I can make out bits and pieces but you'll need to type your question in English.

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to post on the "SO" Portuguese

Comment: ah yes... that was my next guess. Portuguese; my mistake ;-)

Comment: My question is fixed!

Answer (score 2):

The `user_photos` permission that is needed to get access to albums will only work for users with a role in the App if you did not send it in for review. It is called "Login Review": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review